# Installing a fortran package with gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I want to install this package on two different machines. 
http://www.2decomp.org/download.html

On my Mac laptop, when I am using the Makefile.inc.x86 as my Makefile.inc, and do a make, it works straight away without any problem. But on the other machine when I use the same Makefile.inc file, I am getting the following error:

```
[k00603@fe01p05 src]$make
mpif90 -DDOUBLE_PREC -O3 -fcray-pointer -cpp  -c decomp_2d.f90
gfortran: unrecognized option '-cpp'
Warning: decomp_2d.f90:20: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: decomp_2d.f90:21: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: decomp_2d.f90:22: Illegal preprocessor directive
Warning: decomp_2d.f90:23: Illegal preprocessor directive
-------------------------------------------------------
--- around 50 more lines with the same warning --------
-------------------------------------------------------
In file decomp_2d.f90:32

integer, parameter, public :: ga_real_type = MT_F_DBL
                                                  1
Error: Symbol 'mt_f_dbl' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
In file decomp_2d.f90:33

integer, parameter, public :: ga_complex_type = MT_F_DCPL
                                                      1
Error: Symbol 'mt_f_dcpl' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
In file decomp_2d.f90:36
-------------------------------------------------------
------------ a lot of other errors --------------------
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Both of them are Linux x86_64 machines. Any ideas what can I do to install it on the other machine?

Answer (score 1):

Your gfortran is probably too old. `-cpp` option was added in [2008](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=18428). Get a new one, or try `-x f95-cpp-input` or `-x f77-cpp-input` istead.

Comment: Just adding a note that these are preprocessor flags that indicate free form and fixed form Fortran respectively. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gfortran/Preprocessing-and-conditional-compilation.html

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee preprocessing, you could rename `decomp_2d.f90` to `decomp_2d.F90`. I know -cpp should already guarantee it, but it may be worth a try since we don't necessarily know what the underlying compiler is.